# Finding Distance between two coordinates

Tags: linear-algebra, graphing-functions, euclidean-algorithm

[image]

I am a computer guy, I am making some simulations and try to figure out something.

But there is some thing mathematical which I am not able to figure out.

This is my whole area of graph(simulation) given in picture. I have to find the distance between two points like red dots in given picture.
Distance between two points can be found with `Euclidean Distance` but that is for this below given type of graph. Where Y decrease when go below the 0,0. But in my case Y increase while going below.

`Euclidean Distance` will be suitable for my scenario or not ?

If there is any other formula can any one mention it.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes. It will still work just fine.

Why? Because the formula is, roughly,

`EuclideanDistance = Math.sqrt( (x2 - x1) * (x2 - x1) + (y2 - y1)(y2 - y1) );`

If you replace both y1 and y2 by -y1 and -y2, then both factors in the second product are negated, and the product remains the same, because $-1 \times -1 = 1$.